# setup git hook to pull after a push

Tags: git, hook

I have a server setup where I have a project deployed as the same user as the git repo. I'm trying to setup a hook so that when the repository is updated via push, it can update the production files and go live. How would that be done?

Note that I have setup ssh keys and the below command works in ssh.

here is what I have tried.
in /home/user/game.git/hooks/post-recieve

```
#!/bin/sh
#
cd /home/user/game/ && git pull >> echo
```

Comment: Did you make the file executable? (And why would you want to do this?)

Comment: Yes, the permission is 755. Is there an easier way to deploy? Every time someone makes a change, they must do a git pull from ssh to test the project.

Comment: You're getting bitten by the fact that in a hook, the environment varaible `GIT_DIR` is set to a relative path.  When you `cd` elsewhere the `$GIT_DIR` setting becomes incorrect / unwanted.  There are more potential pitfalls than just this one (although for simple uses like this, `unset GIT_DIR` should suffice); if you do anything more complex, look for more information about setting up git hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a page that explains how to do what I was after. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

The command that worked was

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```